About the equation $2^{n+1} = 3^p(2k+1)-1$
Let $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Can we always find  $(n,p) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ such that :
$$2^{n+1} = 3^p(2k+1)-1$$

For $k=0$ the couple $(0,1)$ works.
For $k=1$ the couple $(0,0)$ works.
For $k=2$ the couple $(1,0)$ works.
We'll show that for $k=3$ it is impossible to find a solution. Suppose by contradiction such a couple exists. Then : \begin{align*} 
2^{n+1} \equiv 7 \times 3^p - 1 \hspace{1mm} [7] &\Leftrightarrow 2^{n+1} \equiv -1 \hspace{1mm} [7] \\ 
&\Leftrightarrow 2^{n+1} \equiv 6 \hspace{1mm} [7]
\end{align*}
But mod $7$ only possible values for a power of $2$ are $1,2$ and $4$. Contradiction.

My question : Is this valid ?
Can we write a more elegant solution ?

If your goal is ultimately to just show "no, not all $k$ allow such pairs", you really only have to show the $k=3$ case, and frankly given the brevity of your solution I'm not sure what you could want in something "more elegant"

@PrincessEev Yep firstly I was trying to find a pattern for potential solutions, believing it could be true. I wonder if somebody could see it immediately just by reading the equation.

If $k=13,$ this becomes $2^{n+1}=3^{p+3}-1,$ which I believe is known to not have a solution.

@ThomasAndrews Thanks, great observation !!

More interesting, I think,  is to consider this equation in terms of $p$ rather than $k$.  The multiplicative order of $2$ mod $3^p$ is $2 \cdot 3^{p-1}$, and $2^{3^{p-1}} \equiv -1 \pmod {3^p}$. Of course, when $(2^{n+1}+1)/3^p$ is an integer it must be odd.
So for each $p$ the solutions are $n = (2j+1) \cdot 3^{p-1}-1$, $k = ((2^{(2j+1) \cdot 3^{p-1}}+1)/3^p -1)/2$.
